# Load specific layer from GML to GeoPandas

Tags: python, layers, geopandas, gml, ordnance-survey

I got a GML file from Ordnance Survey's Topography layer. The file has 5 layers in total (image from loading to QGIS):

[image]

I would like to load the file to python and I saw that GeoPandas has GML support so I am doing this:

```
db = gpd.read_file('pth/to/5221132-NS7010', driver='GML')
```

But this seems to load only the Cartographic text layer (the db contains 1039 points):

```
len(db) # 1039
```

Is there a way to specify the specific layer (by layer id) that I want loaded? Or even load everything and the choose the one I am interested in?

Comment: You can pass `layer=` keyword to `read_file`.

Comment: Yes indeed! Can you please make this an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GeoPandas allows the `layer` keyword in `read_file`.

```py
db = gpd.read_file('pth/to/5221132-NS7010', driver='GML', layer="my_layer_name")
```